# cs50x - Tideman - 2024

Tags: cs50

In this problem i have this problem with my "lock-pairs" function..

I made a function to check if a loop is formed or not...

and here i have made a function that does check it by putting edges in a array..

and then checking if the winner i.e. the even indexes(0,2,..) elements is equal to the latest edge loser..

the gives the correct answer always and also makes any edge that makes a cycle go away..

can somebody help pointing out errors for this..

this algorithm uses an array to check if the edges form a loop or not;

```
`bool cycle(int current_size, int edges[], int winner)
 {
    int loser = edges[current_size - 1];

     if (current_size <= 0)
     {
         return false;
     }

     else if (winner == loser)
     {
         return true;
     }

     if (cycle(current_size - 2, edges, winner))
     {
         return true;
     }

     return false;
 }


and below is the block of lock pairs function..

void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    int edges[pair_count * 2];
    int current_size = 0;

    //main loop to lock the pairs..!
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        //if there are less than 2 edges::
        if (i < 2)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;

            edges[current_size] = pairs[i].winner;
            current_size++;

            edges[current_size] = pairs[i].loser;
            current_size++;
        }

        //now for more than 2 edges..!
        else
        {
            edges[current_size] = pairs[i].winner;
            current_size++;
            edges[current_size] = pairs[i].loser;
            current_size++;

            if (!cycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser))
            {
                locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
            }

            else
            {
                current_size -= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```